# Chocolate Vending Machine with Python GUI // Cannot Total Prices Up and Print Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

Right here, I am trying to create a GUI calculator in Python for a class assignment called 'Chocolate Vending Machine'. Basically, students are assigned to create a GUI using Python's Tkinter. We list a couple of chocolate brands such as Snickers, Twix and Mars and put a price tag on each of them. The user goes through these steps:

1. Input a float value of how much money he has (can be any value)
2. He selects how many of each chocolate he wants
3. That value is printed to the console under: "Total Cost"
4. The original balance (how much money he originally had) minus Total Cost prints the new balance

Please refer to the code below, and perhaps copy and paste it into your Python application:

Let me try to explain what the problem is. **If you look from line 42 to 55**, you will see my function "Total()", which, in theory, adds up all of the quantities and prices of chocolate that the user would like. The code that says: "Total.set(CostOfMeal)" should print out the total cost on the right hand middle box next to "Total Cost".

But it doesn't. When I try to press the "Total" button, it doesn't work.  instead, Python gives me this message:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1550, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/s190528/PycharmProjects/CSP/GUI Testing 2.py", line 55, in Total
    Total.set(CostOfMeal)
**AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set'**

Could somebody possibly help me with this, or better yet, provide code that would add up all the values and print it? Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1300x600+0+0")
root.title("Oli's Chocolate Machine")
root.configure(bg='powder blue')
lbl_title = tk.Label(root,text="Welcome. Please input your balance and select your chocolate of choice.", bg = 'powder blue')
lbl_title.pack()

text_Input = StringVar()
operator = ""

#==================================Setting the Frame=======================================


Tops = Frame(root, width=1600, height=50, bg="powder blue", relief=SUNKEN)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width=1200, height=700, bg="powder blue", relief=SUNKEN)
f1.pack(side=LEFT)

f2 = Frame(root, width=300, height=700, bg="powder blue",relief=SUNKEN)
f2.pack(side=RIGHT)

#==================================Time=======================================

localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))


#==================================System Information=======================================

lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('simplifica', 50, 'bold'), text="Oli's Chocolate Machine", fg="Steel Blue", bd=10, anchor='w')
lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)

lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('simplifica', 20), text=localtime, fg="Steel Blue",
                bd=10, anchor='w')
lblInfo.grid(row=1, column=0)

def Total():
    AmtOfTwix = (float(Twix.get()))
    AmtOfSnickers = (float(Snickers.get()))
    AmtOfMarsBar = (float(MarsBar.get()))
    AmtOfGodiva = (float(Godiva.get()))

    CostOfTwix = AmtOfTwix * 1.59
    CostOfSnickers = AmtOfSnickers * 1.79
    CostOfMarsBar = AmtOfMarsBar * 2.19
    CostOfGodiva = AmtOfGodiva * 3.99

    CostOfMeal = ("USD$" + str('%.2f'% (CostOfTwix + CostOfSnickers + CostOfMarsBar + CostOfGodiva)))

    Total.set(CostOfMeal)

def qExit():
    root.destroy()

def Reset():
    Twix.set(0)
    Snickers.set(0)
    MarsBar.set(0)
    Godiva.set(0)
    InitialBalance.set(0)
    Cost.set(0)
    FinalBalance.set(0)

#-------------------

Twix=DoubleVar()
Snickers=DoubleVar()
MarsBar=DoubleVar()
Godiva=DoubleVar()

lblTwix = Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text='Twix',bg = 'powder blue',bd=19,anchor='w')
lblTwix.grid(row=2,column=0)
txtTwix = Entry(f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=Twix,bd=10,insertwidth=4,
                bg='powder blue',justify='right')
txtTwix.grid(row=2,column=1)

lblSnickers = Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text='Snickers', bg = 'powder blue',bd=19,anchor='w')
lblSnickers.grid(row=4,column=0)
txtSnickers = Entry(f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=Snickers,bd=10,insertwidth=4,
                bg='powder blue',justify='right')
txtSnickers.grid(row=4,column=1)

lblMarsBar = Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text='Mars Bar', bg = 'powder blue',bd=19,anchor='w')
lblMarsBar.grid(row=6,column=0)
txtMarsBar = Entry(f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=MarsBar,bd=10,insertwidth=4,
                bg='powder blue',justify='right')
txtMarsBar.grid(row=6,column=1)

lblGodiva = Label(f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'), text="Godiva", bg = 'powder blue',bd=19, anchor='w')
lblGodiva.grid(row=9, column=0)
txtGodiva = Entry(f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=Godiva,bd=10,insertwidth=4,
                bg='powder blue',justify='right')
txtGodiva.grid(row=9,column=1)

#==================================Balance, Cost=======================================

InitialBalance=DoubleVar()
Cost=DoubleVar()
FinalBalance=DoubleVar()

lblInitialBalance = Label(f1,font=('arial',20,'bold'), text="Initial Balance", bg = 'powder blue', bd=29, anchor='w')
lblInitialBalance.grid(row=2, column=10)
txtInitialBalance=Entry(f1,font=('arial',20,'bold'), textvariable=InitialBalance, bd=28, insertwidth=4,
                   bg='powder blue', justify='right')
txtInitialBalance.grid(row=2, column=12)

lblCost = Label(f1,font=('arial',20,'bold'), text="Total Cost", bg = 'powder blue',bd=29, anchor='w')
lblCost.grid(row=4, column=10)
txtCost=Entry(f1,font=('arial',20,'bold'), textvariable=Cost, bd=28, insertwidth=4,
                   bg='powder blue', justify='right')
txtCost.grid(row=4, column=12)

lblFinalBalance = Label(f1,font=('arial',20,'bold'), text="Final Balance", bg = 'powder blue',bd=29, anchor='w')
lblFinalBalance.grid(row=6, column=10)
txtFinalBalance=Entry(f1,font=('arial',20,'bold'), textvariable=FinalBalance, bd=28, insertwidth=4,
                   bg='powder blue', justify='right')
txtFinalBalance.grid(row=6, column=12)

#==================================More Buttons=======================================

btnTotal = Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16,fg="black",font=('arial',20,'bold'),width=6,text="Total",bg="powder blue",
                  command=Total).grid(row=11,column=3)

btnReset = Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16,fg="black",font=('arial',20,'bold'),width=6,text="Reset",bg="powder blue",
                  command=Reset).grid(row=11,column=4)

btnExit = Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16,fg="black",font=('arial',20,'bold'),width=6,text="Exit",bg="powder blue",
                  command=qExit).grid(row=11,column=5)
#--------------------------------------------------------------

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please consider reducing it down to a [mcve]

Comment: "... or better yet, *provide code*" is where you lost me.

Comment: this code is too much

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. Start by reading and understanding the error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set'`. You have a function named `Total`. Why do you think your `Total` function has a method named `set`?

Comment: The reason why I added this much code is because it wouldn't work when copied and pasted into Python without each line of code, sorry.

Comment: @Oli I'm sorry but that's not enough reason. If you can't create a [mcve] to the question you're asking, then the chances are you'll learn nothing from the answers that fix your code. Which makes the question a waste of time including your own.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try to be better next time.

Comment: We don't need you to copy/paste code. What you should do instead is write a _new_ program specifically for this question. It will help you narrow your focus down to only the lines that are really important. Often, the very act of doing that will help you see what the problem is without our help.

Comment: Note that it's not exactly too late for this question either, you can always [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `line 55` and replace `Total.set` with this

```
txtCost.insert(0, CostOfMeal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `Total` as a function (`def Total():`) and then appear to be trying to use it as some object that has a `set` method. That's why you're getting the AttributeError.